# Open aspx from wpf project on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Hey I wrote an aspx file on a web application project, now i transferd the aspx file to a wpf project and i want to load it in a browser.

I'am getting an error when the browser loads:

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Here is my code:

XAML:

```
 <Button Content="Press Here" Height="145" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,175,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="271" Background="{x:Null}" Click="AddNewUser" Foreground="#FFF7F1F1" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" />
```

C#

```
 private void AddNewUser(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Default.aspx");

    }
```

Could anyone tell me what i'am doing wrong?, is it even possible to open an aspx file in web browser?, if not whats the solution?

Kind reggards

Comment: you cannot mix web application file with WPF project.

Comment: then how can i open an aspx file in a window application project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to run an ASPX page directly within a web browser. That's not possible. An ASPX WebForm needs to be hosted on a web server, executed by this web server and the resulting HTML sent to the browser. Don't forget that browsers do not even know what an ASPX page is, not how to properly render. Web browsers understand and work with HTML, CSS and javascript.

So the correct way is to host this WebForm on a web server and then specify the address of this server:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://mydomain.com/Default.aspx");
```

If you don't have a web server then you could retrieve the generated HTML and then use this HTML in your application:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("file:///c:/work/Default.html");
```